# Auto Save or Prompt before navigating away from text editors in Kentico CMSDesk not working

Tags: kentico

Auto Save or Prompt before navigating away from text editors in Kentico CMSDesk not working. I already set the Settings -> Content Management -> Prompt to save changes on exit to checked, but didn't work. Can somebody help me.

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to enable the developer tools in chrome or firebug in firefox and check, if there are any javascript errors in  your pages. it's possible that some custom javascript interferes with this check. Check for any errors and try to resolve them. Or, as a test, try creating a completely blank page in the content tree, with only an editable region and disable any master page inheritance so there won't be any custom code used on your page and test, if it works there. If it does, then keep adding your scripts and test to see which component or script is causing the issue. Also make sure your settings are enabled on a site level in the settings application.

Comment: Do you any idea for this one. I think this make sense, please see the attachment : [link](http://prntscr.com/bnbclj)

Comment: This is our internal jQuery namespace... this is definitely the issue causing your problems. It means that our jQuery wasn't loaded properly and I think that's why this feature isn't working for you. It looks like our jQuery isn't registered properly. There are different possible causes, such as missing file/reference, conflict in your and our javascript etc.

Comment: if this website has been upgraded then it may be because the upgrade wasn't performed properly. You didn't mention the exact version you are using 8/8.1/8.2? You could download a clean installation of that version and check/compare the files to see if tehre are any differences to rule out upgrade issues.

Comment: I don't see in your screenshot if you've removed your custom components but that's what I'd do at first to rule out any comnflicts...everything else is much more work.

Answer (score 0):

Which version and hotfix do you use? I suppose you are using v7 (or less - because of CMSDesk). Please note there were some bug fixes related to prompt in CMSDesk (eg. in 7.0.80).

> Content editing - The ‘Prompt to save changes on exit’ setting didn’t work correctly

You can find more information about hotfixes and fixed bugs [here](http://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes).

edit: after additional info (screen from your console) I think you have registered your own jquery and you don`t have registered it in no conflict mode. Can you agree? Could you register your jquery in nonconflict mode and try the prompt behavior again?

Comment: ohh crap really, I used v8, is there any way you know to prevent this? Please.

Comment: Are you sure you are using v8? There is no CMSDesk in version 8.

Comment: ohhh sorry, but I call the whole Dashboard as a CMSDesk hehehe, so do you have any idea for that problem?

Comment: There has also been a bug in v8.2 which was fixed in HF 20: Pages - Users weren't prompted to save changes when editing page-level permissions
When editing the page-level permissions (ACLs) for a user or a role, users were not prompted to save the changes when switching to another user or role in the list. - maybe it has something to do with it.